# How to draw shapes using a 2D array to describe the shape?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, graphics, rectangles

I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with this code.

I am trying to draw an `L` shape using a 2D array. For some reason, the code is drawing a big box instead of an `L` shape. I stepped through the code and the `(x, y)` positions are fine.
I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

```
private int[,] matrix = new int[3, 3] {
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 1 }
};

private void aCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    var gfx = e.Graphics;
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Tomato);
    for (var x = 0; x <= matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; x++) 
        for (var y = 0; y <= matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; y++)
           if (matrix[x, y] != 0) {
               var rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 30, 30);
               gfx.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
           }
}
```

Comment: You're painting 4 rectangles of the same size (30, 30) at a slightly different location (from (0,1) to (2,2)). Do you need to use this kind of array to paint shapes? Usually, an Array/List<Point> is used instead. Maybe, with a [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) class (not necessary, tough).

Comment: The simplest way to draw a shape with striaght lines is using DrawLines or FillPolygon. In your case you may want to consider each element a pixel. For that use Draw/FillRectangle but make the distances and the sizes equal, maybe by  simly changing to var rect = new Rectangle(x*30, y*30, 30, 30)

Comment: The naive answer would be that you forgot to multiply up the coordinates of those rectangles, `new Rectangle(x, y ...`, I wonder how high `x` and `y` goes? You sure you didn't forgot to multiply by 30? `new Rectangle(x * 30, y * 30, ...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is painting 4 rectangles of the same size `(30, 30)` at a slightly different location (from `(0, 1)` to `(2, 2)`), since you're just using the array indexers as the `Location` coordinates.

Simple solution, using the `Rectangle.Size` value you're showing now:

Increment the `(x, y)` values of the `Rectangle.Location` by an offset defined by the Rectangle's `Height` and `Width`, multiplying the current `(x, y)` positions in the matrix by these offsets:
(Note that the `x` index is used to multiply the height offset; of course the opposite for `y`)

```
private int[,] matrix = new int[3, 3] {
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 1 }
};

Size rectSize = new Size(30, 30);
private void aCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int xPosition = 0;
    int yPosition = 0;
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Tomato)) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; x++)
        for (var y = 0; y <= matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; y++)
        {
            xPosition = y * rectSize.Width;
            yPosition = x * rectSize.Height;

            if (matrix[x, y] != 0) {
                var rect = new Rectangle(new Point(xPosition, yPosition), rectSize);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: L shape]

With this matrix:

```
private int[,] matrix = new int[3, 3] {
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1 }
};
```

You get this:

[image: T shape]

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome! Wish I could upvote this over and over.