# Creating a Map Grid WinForms.... Arrays

Tags: c#, winforms

First Post.
Basically I am trying create a map grid based on the array in Winforms.
I'm failing though.
This is what I've got so far

The problem is it displays everything as one color. Whereas I want it to be a certain color based on the array.

The issue I think is the foreach loop in the for loop. As the foreach loop is within the second for loop,  it's probably going to repeat for ever i and then for every j.

But I am too dumb to know how to sort it.
I know winforms is not ideal for this and I do not really want to redo the code I just kinda wanna make this work if possible.

namespace Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
int TILE_SIZE = 64;
int MAP_NUM_ROWS = 11;
int MAP_NUM_COLS = 15;
List items = new List();

```
    int[] mapGrid =
    {
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

};




    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newTest();
        
    }

    private void newTest()
    {


        for (var i = 0; i < MAP_NUM_ROWS; i++) //
        {

            for (var j = 0; j < MAP_NUM_COLS; j++)

            {
                PictureBox Walls = new PictureBox();
                Walls.Location = new Point(i * TILE_SIZE, j * TILE_SIZE);  
                Walls.Height = TILE_SIZE;
                Walls.Width = TILE_SIZE;
                Walls.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;




                foreach (int test in mapGrid)

                {


                    if (test == 0)
                    {

                        Walls.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        items.Add(Walls);
                        this.Controls.Add(Walls);



                    }

                    if (test == 1)
                    {

                        Walls.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                        items.Add(Walls);
                        this.Controls.Add(Walls);


                    }
                }


                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4RFv.png)

I've tried using Panels and Flowlayoutpanels and TableLayout panels. The issue seems to be the loops and I am too tired to see the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55783606/7444103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not be looping over the grid inside that main outer loop. YOu want

```
  int test = mapGrid[i*MAP_NUM_COLS + j]
```

ie , pick out the cell that matched the row / col you are filling

Comment: Yea, I'm still getting to grips with C# Thanks for the answer. All good :)